Vertex not showing in my cube with subdivision
The problem I have is that I can not edit my circle because it has no faces or vertices, I only have 8 vertices that are the corners but I can not edit it, the goal would be to split half a circle, put mirror effect and in the future sculpt the shape of a face and create a character. But first I have to solve this. I have tried everything that chatGPT has recommended me:
If you are still having trouble seeing the smoothed and subdivided geometry of your object correctly in Blender, here are some additional suggestions you might want to consider:
Check the modifier application:
Make sure you have applied the Subdivision Surface modifier correctly before switching to edit mode. This is crucial for converting the smoothed geometry to the actual geometry of the object. Select the object, go to the modifier panel (right sidebar, press N to open if necessary), and click the "Apply" button under the Subdivision Surface modifier. Adjust the display settings:
After applying the modifier, verify that you are viewing the object in "On Cage" mode while in edit mode. This should show the smoothed geometry, although you can still edit the actual geometry of the object. You can change this setting from the modifier properties panel. Enable subdivision lines:
At the top right of the 3D Viewport window, turn on "Subdivision Lines" from the Overlays menu. This will allow you to see the lines representing the subdivisions generated by the modifier, which can help you better understand the topology of the object. Verify the selection and display modes:
Make sure you are in Vertex Select mode when you are trying to view or select the object's vertices. Verify that you are not filtering out certain types of elements (vertices, edges, faces) from the selection options in the edit mode toolbar. Review Blender settings:
Using Blender 4.1


hello please use english   ;)

It is normal that you can only edit the 8 vertices, your object is still a cube, a Subdivision Surface modifier only create virtual faces, you can't edit them, unless you apply the modifier (Ctrl A on the modifier)

Thank you for your answer
but i still have doubt
isnt' any way to see it even if its a cube? Can i just create new existing vertex with any modifier that isn't subdivision? im new in blender so idk how to do it,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-XYryP_GU8o i am seeing this tutorial and in the 2:00 minute he make a cube, with circle shape and the edge and vertex appear for him

Uncheck "Optimal Display" in the modifier settings

For future reference, don’t include what ChatGPT told you in your question. It is not a reliable source of information by any means, and there’s just no reason for that additional text that we already know is unhelpful.
